# Update single value in reducer object without erasing existing data

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My goal is to update the `pause` value in my ruducer's object without deleting any of the other data.

Here is my ruducer:

```js
export const initialState = {
  audio: {
    sound: false,
    index: 0,
    name: '',
    image: '',
    username: '',
    pause: false,
  },
};
```

And here is it's case:

```js
case 'TRIGGER_AUDIO':
      return {
        ...state,
        audio: action.payload,
      };
```

Here is how I access the `audio` values:

```js
  const [{ audio }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
```

And this is how I'm trying to update it when I press a button:

```js
<TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() =>
                dispatch({
                  type: 'TRIGGER_AUDIO',
                  payload: {
                    ...state,
                    pause: true,
                  },
                })
              }>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like,

```
case 'TRIGGER_AUDIO':
    return {
    ...state,
    audio: { ...state.audio, pause: action.payload.pause },
  }
```

Dispatch will be like

```
 dispatch({type: 'TRIGGER_AUDIO', payload:{pause: true} })
```

Or if you need to work with your logic, it should be

```
<TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() =>
                dispatch({
                  type: 'TRIGGER_AUDIO',
                  payload: {
                    ...state.audio,
                    pause: true,
                  },
                })
              }>

case 'TRIGGER_AUDIO':
      return {
        ...state,
        audio: action.payload,
      };
```

Comment: The third one is the style I like, but it's not working? It still deletes everything :(

Comment: did you try the 1st one?

Comment: how are you accessing the state property in dispatch?

Comment: And the 1st messes up my code for some reason

Comment: You need to change the disptach as well, for the first type